# Grid Deselect Multiple Checkboxes with shift click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

We are trying to get our react ag-grid checkbox functionality to work like gmail where if you shift click multiple checkboxes that are already selected it will deselect them (see screenshot below). The problem is during onRowSelected it will give me the rows that are already selected but I can't find the range that was selected. onSelectionChanged will get me the range selected but doesn't tell me the row that was just selected so that I can get the value to deselect the checkboxes. Anyone have any suggestions?

[image]